# Modifying components in a changset

Tags: change-set

I have found [conflicting answers](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DaEyQAK) to this question so am asking it again.

If I add an Apex class to a change set and then subsequently modify the class does the version in the change set reflect this change? Or will the 'original' version I added to the change set be the one that is uploaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the link which you have specified and the answer looks straight and correct to me.

Unless you upload the changeset any changes you made in components (APex class, VF page, Lightning, Triggers etc.) Will be included in that changeset. Once you have uploaded the changes set then any future changes won't be included. If you want to include them then just clone the existing one and update that again.

That's why we can keep adding components in changeset and once done with development and testing we can upload it.

Comment: In the link one person says the opposite of what the accepted is (i.e. that changes are locked once put into the change set) and somebody below agrees with him. That's why I thought there were some conflicting answers. Thanks for your answer though, I think you are right